# Crash when switching apps with non default launchers

Tags: launcher, system-apps, 9.0-pie, nokia-6

I just updated a Nokia 6.1 (TA-1054) to Android P and when I change the launcher from the default launcher3 to anything else it keeps opening launcher3 when I try to switch apps and crashes.

I tried rooting the device and trying to disable and uninstall it with no luck. Any ideas?

I tried the following so far:

```
./adb shell pm disable --user 0 com.android.launcher3
./adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.launcher3
./adb shell rm /system/priv-app/NBCLauncher/NBCLauncher.apk
```

[Video](https://youtu.be/MF7oNg0FV3E)

Comment: Please [edit] to mention what device